# AngularJS ng-model binding with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am dynamically creating elements based on json data that i get from a service. The elements are being created fine but the values are not being bound to the model via ng-model. I tried putting the function in $timeout to force $apply(). Even that did not work. Following is the code :

```
function InstructionsCtrl($http, ApiCallFactory, $timeout) {
    var insCtrl = this;
    insCtrl.data = [];
    insCtrl.answers = {};
    insCtrl.questionGroup = ApiCallFactory.questionGroup;

    $timeout(function(){
        var html = "";
        var questionSet;
        for (var tempQuestionSet in insCtrl.questionGroup) {
            if (insCtrl.questionGroup.hasOwnProperty(tempQuestionSet)) {
                questionSet = insCtrl.questionGroup[tempQuestionSet];
                for (var question in questionSet) {
                    if (questionSet.hasOwnProperty(question)) {
                        if (questionSet[question].type == 'text') {
                            html += ' <div class="form-group"> <label for="text">' + questionSet[question].text + '</label> <input type="text" class="hi" id="text" ng-model="insCtrl.answers.';
                            html += tempQuestionSet + '.' + question + '" value ="text" name="radio1"> </div> '
                        }
                        else if (questionSet[question].type == 'select') {
                            var noOfOptions = questionSet[question].values.length;
                            html += ' <div class="form-group"> <label for="radio">' + questionSet[question].text;
                            html += '<select>';
                            for (var i = 0; i < noOfOptions; i++) {
                                html += '<option>' + questionSet[question].values[i] + '</option>';
                            }
                            html += '</select></div>'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var formContainer = $('#jsonTest');
        formContainer.empty();
        formContainer.prepend(html);
    });
}
```

I've currently added ng-model only to the text type fields. Pls let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Creating html strings and appending to dom won't work without using `$compile` and approach is all wrong for angular app. All you should be doing is working with the data model and let angular manage the dom. Most of the code shown would disappear by using `ng-repeat` in view

Comment: The issue is that the view is not fixed. I wont even know what elements the dom would contain until i get the json data. So using the html string was the only way i could think of. So to use $compile  should be working with a directive if i'm not wrong?

Comment: well there are numerous other logical directives also. I know it's hard to think differently. Take jQuery.js right out of your page. Always think of the data model first. Even if it means a slight remapping of the input data. I don't see anything in your scenario that won't be easily managed mostly with angular core directives and you could modularize some of it with custom directive

Comment: Thanks. I'll try my luck writing a custom directive and go from there. If you can give me an overview of what possible angular attributes might help my case, i would highly appreciate it. Also, is using a directive the only good way to add/update html ?

Comment: start with `ng-repeat` . Build an html template the way you need it to be and then you add in some conditionals like `ng-if` or `ng-switch` ... then do custom directive as you see a need